# Конструкция else if (...) {...}

Tags: javascript

Не могу разобраться, почему конструкция вида отрабатывает

```
if ((buffer != 0)){
    operation = 'plus';
}
if ((buffer != 0) && (buffer2 != 0)){
    alert(buffer + buffer2);
}
```

А такого вида нет

```
if((buffer != 0)){
    operation = 'plus';
}else if((buffer != 0) && (buffer2 != 0)){
    alert(buffer + buffer2);
}
```

Во втором случае условие else if не выполняется, почему? Что не так?

Answer (score 6):

Дополняю к [@Gorets](/users/3608/gorets), у вас вообще в логике ошибка.

Обозначим `(buffer != 0)` как А, `(buffer2 != 0)` как B, имеем

```
if (A) {
  // code, A == true
} else if (A && B) {
  // эта часть никогда не выполнится, 
  // т.к. до else дойдет _только_ если A == false, 
  // а (false && B) == false. 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Все просто.

В первом варианте проверяются 2 условия ПОДРЯД - проверяются оба.

А во втором - 2-е условие проверяется только в противном случае, так как первое условие прошло - второе выполнять не надо.